# Laptop unable to start due to packaging failure

Tags: boot, 19.10

My dad started his laptop today but it wouldn't boot due to packaging error. He has Ubuntu 19.10 on his machine. Does anyone know how he can get his machine working again? I don't have enough knowledge to sort this and he's new to [using] Linux.

[image: Unpacking Failure]

Comment: Is Secure Boot on?  Temporarily disable Secure Boot in the system BIOS to get online.  THEN they have to get the signed linux kernel image or apply their own local signature to the kernel to make it load properly.  Likely this is due to an unsigned driver, and Secure Boot will barf over it.

Comment: @ThomasWard ta for your response. Here's the reply from my dad:

"Thanks Thomas but that's a little bit cryptic for me.
HOW do I disable secure boot?
Where do I get a "signed Linux kernel image"?
What do you mean with "barf"?"

Comment: Disabling secure boot is beyond the scope of this site as it is different per each system.  If he just disables secure boot that should be sufficient.  However, as I said, that's beyond the scope of Ask Ubuntu.  He'd have to look up the process (or you could) for the specific system in question.